# SUM(CASE WHEN ...) returns a greater number than COUNT(DISTINCT..)

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have written a query in two models, but I can't figure out why the second query returns a greater number than the first one; while the number that the first one, COUNT(DISTINCT...) returns is correct:

```
    WITH types(id) AS (VALUES('{1, 4, 5, 3}'::INTEGER[])),
    date_gen64 AS
    (
        SELECT CAST (generate_series(date '10/1/2017', date '11/15/2017', interval
          '1 day') AS date) as days        ORDER BY days)   

        SELECT cl.class_date AS c_date,
               count(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN co.id = 1 THEN  p.id END)), 
       count(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN co.id = 2 THEN  p.id END))
        FROM person p
             JOIN envelope e ON e.personID = p.id 
             JOIN "class" cl on cl.id = p.classID
             JOIN course co ON co.id = cl.course_id AND co.id = 1
             JOIN types ON cr.type_id = ANY (types.id) 
             RIGHT JOIN date_gen64 dg ON dg.days = cl.class_date
      GROUP BY cl.class_date
      ORDER BY cl.class_date
```

The above query returns 26 but following query returns 27!
    The reason why I rewrote it with SUM is that the first query 
was too slow. But my question is that why the second one counts more?

```
WITH types(id) AS (VALUES('{1, 4, 5, 3}'::INTEGER[]))    
SELECT tmpcl.days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tmp80.course_id = 1 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0     END), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN tmp80.course_id = 2 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0     END)        
        FROM (
       SELECT CAST (generate_series(date '10/1/2017', date '11/15/2017',
     interval     '1 day')   AS date) as days     ORDER BY days) tmpcl
       LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT  DISTINCT  p.id AS "person_id",
                    cl.class_date AS c_date,
                    co.id AS "course_id"                  
                    FROM person p
                    JOIN envelope e ON e.personID = p.id 
                    JOIN "class" cl on cl.id = p.classID
                    JOIN course co ON co.id = cl.course_id
                    JOIN types ON cr.type_id = ANY (types.id) 
                    WHERE co.id IN ( 1  , 2 )
                   ) tmp80 ON tmpcl.days = tmp80.class_date
      GROUP BY tmpcl.days
      ORDER BY tmpcl.days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can theoretically have multiple people enrolled in the same class on the same day. Indeed that would seem to be the main point of having *classes*. So each time there are multiple people assigned to the same class on the same day you can have a higher count than you would in your first query. Does that make sense?

You don't appear to be using `p.id` in that inner query so simply remove it and your counts should match.

```
WITH types(id) AS (VALUES('{1, 4, 5, 3}'::INTEGER[]))    
SELECT tmpcl.days,
        SUM(CASE WHEN tmp80.course_id = 1 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0     END), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN tmp80.course_id = 2 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0     END)        
        FROM (
       SELECT CAST (generate_series(date '10/1/2017', date '11/15/2017',
     interval     '1 day')   AS date) as days     ORDER BY days) tmpcl
       LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT cl.class_date AS c_date,
                    co.id AS "course_id"
                    FROM person p
                    JOIN envelope e ON e.personID = p.id 
                    JOIN "class" cl on cl.id = p.classID
                    JOIN course co ON co.id = cl.course_id
                    JOIN types ON cr.type_id = ANY (types.id) 
                    WHERE co.id IN ( 1  , 2 )
                   ) tmp80 ON tmpcl.days = tmp80.class_date
      GROUP BY tmpcl.days
      ORDER BY tmpcl.days
```

Comment: Thank you Bernie, but in your query it counts the number of classes not people, I added p.id to the select list of your query and it works fine now